# Save templates to file suddenly stopped working?

Tags: templates

I have a clients site which has been working fine for a year or so, I have been doing a few updates to it over the last few days, now suddenly 'Saving Templates to File' has broken. If I make any changes to the templates via the control panel or via my html editor and save it wipes the whole of the file. The only way I can make any changes is to do them via the control panel and make sure 'Save Template to File' is unchecked.

I have checked and the templates folder is set to 777, and the location of that folder hasn't changed.

Does anyone have any advice? or a solution?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: check with your host to make ensure that ownership of the folder hasn't changed. That happened to me after my host updated some server software.

Comment: check also if was not any server update and you don't have safe_mode = ON

Comment: Hi Erbert, I'd suggest writing up your solution as an answer and then accepting it once enough time has passed to assist people having the same issue down the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you very much for your helpful answers. It turns out it was much more straight forward. I contacted the host and found out that the client's site had gone over it's space limit, so any template I was trying to change or create other than through the control panel wan't being written. Thanks again.